# Somewhat specific question about Guitar String Gauge

Tags: guitar, string-gauge

If a guitar is setup for 011-056, would i need to re=setup my guitar for 011-049 or 011-52 set of strings.

Comment: Check this answer https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1467/do-i-need-to-have-my-guitar-re-set-up-if-i-change-the-string-gauge?rq=1, your question is just a specific case.

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't change your tuning or your string height (from the fretboard), then no, you would not.
Your new string may are fatter and with different gauge, but they are design to have same string tension.
However, if you prefer different string height due to different string gauge you will definitely need a new setup for your guitar.

Comment: Completely inaccurate answer.